# Printing names in JSP through a LinkedList not printing in order

Tags: java, postgresql, jsp

I'm trying to apply a sort order to an HTML search form, and print the results in the specified order. I can't figure out for the life of me why it wouldn't work unless there's something about LinkedLists I don't know. I am relatively new to development so that's possible. Please keep in mind this is for an assignment for my coding boot camp, so while I appreciate all advice, we're being asked not to import any libraries other that what was provided and we're also being asked not to use servlets. Code below

This chunk is found in my JDBC.

```
    public List<Customer> searchAndSortCustomers(String search, String sort) {
        List<Customer> customers = new LinkedList<>();

        String query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, activebool FROM customer WHERE first_name ILIKE ? OR last_name ILIKE ? ORDER BY ?";
        SqlRowSet result = jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet(query, "%" + search + "%", "%" + search + "%", sort);

        while(result.next()) {
            customers.add(mapRowToCustomer(result));
        }

        return customers;
    }
```

Helper method mapRowToCustomer

```
private Customer mapRowToCustomer(SqlRowSet result) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();

        customer.setFirstName(result.getString("first_name"));
        customer.setLastName(result.getString("last_name"));
        customer.setEmail(result.getString("email"));
        customer.setActive(result.getBoolean("activebool"));

        return customer;
    }
```

JSP page with form, etc.

```
<form method="GET" action="customerSearch">

    <label for="search">First or Last Name</label>
    <input name="search" type="text"/>

    <br>
    <br>

    <label for="sort">Sort By</label>
    <select name="sort">
        <option value="first_name">First Name</option>
        <option value="last_name">Last Name</option>
        <option value="activebool">Active</option>
    </select>

    <br>
    <br>

    <input type="submit"/>

</form>

<c:if test="${not empty param.search}">
    <table id="customer-flex">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Active</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach var="customer" items="${customers}">
            <tr>
                <td>${customer.firstName} ${customer.lastName}</td>
                <td>${customer.email}</td>
                <td>${customer.active}</td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</c:if>
```

The query works in dbvisualizer with copy/pasted values just to double check that I didn't make any spelling mistakes for the db column headers. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: You can not pass the column to be sorted by as a `?` parameter to the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Oh, odd. That did seem to be the problem! I'll just have to set up some if/else statements now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"You can not pass the column to be sorted by as a ? parameter to the ORDER BY clause. – a_horse_with_no_name"

This was the correct answer, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using String.format, I hope this will help you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sort = "first_name";
    String query = "SELECT first_name, last_name, email, activebool FROM customer WHERE first_name ILIKE ? OR last_name ILIKE ? ORDER BY %s";
    query = getQueryWithOrderBy(query , sort);
    System.out.println(query);

}

private static String getQueryWithOrderBy(String query, String sort) {
    query = String.format(query,sort);
    return query;
}
```